# Setting permissions in disk partitions

Tags: partitioning, permissions, hard-drive

I am new to Linux in general and am presently using Ubuntu 16.04 distro. Recently, I have been fiddling around with disk partitioning with the aim of putting all my documents on HDD disk and keep all my applications installed on an SSD disk. The whole procedure of what I did is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk/1059073#1059073) (in the provided answer).

This works fine, however I have encountered one annoyance. In order to change and save any files from the HDD, I have to first copy them to the Desktop and modify them there. I believe this is due to the fact, that I moved all my files into a folder, which requires permission to be accessed every time I wish to modify any document. However I do not know, how to remove this permission request and whether that is a good idea in the first place. Any ideas of how to permanently remove this need for permission?

I thank you all for any provided answers.

Comment: And where is this folder located, some where in `/` or `/home/$USER` directories?

Comment: Yes, this is the location `/home/$USER/mnt/data/`. Note, that I did not create this file, but it was there as a part of distro installation, apparently. I chose it, as it was also chosen in the tutorial for disk partitioning that I was following.

Comment: Run `sudo ls -l /home/$USER/mnt  | cut -d" " -f5-` and lets see the ownership!

Comment: Actually, I realized the file is under `Computer/mnt/data` (having run the above command, the directory couldn't be found). Thus, `sudo ls -l /mnt | cut -d" " -f5-` gave the output `4096 jul 24 19:06 data`

Comment: Remove the cut part and give us the result.

Comment: I assume you meant `sudo ls -l /mnt`. It gives `total 4
drwxrwxrwx 9 $USER $USER 4096 jul 24 19:06 data`